# How to get filesystem path from mongoengine FileField

Tags: python, mongodb, path, mongoengine, filefield

I need to obtain path from a `FileField`, in order to check it against a given file system path, to know if the file I am inserting into mongo database is already present.
Is it possible?

All I get is a `GridFSProxy`, but I am unable to understand how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't since it stores the data into database. If you need to store the original path then you can create an EmbeddedDocument which contains a FileField and a StringField with the path string. But remember that the stored file and the file you might find on that path are not the same

Comment: I just see your posting date. I hope this could be helpful for someone else

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. In the end I figured out that every file I put into database it's, as you said, stored directly into database (not only its reference). So comparing it to a file in the file system doesn't make sense, because it does not refer to original path.